# How to crop small image basing on big image

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

This is quite challenging and that's why I have come here for help as a last resort. I have an image on my drive that am trying to crop, the image itself is much bigger but in the browser I lessened it's width to make it all visible and also I kept the image ratio size.

The browser version of the original hard-disk image is exactly the same only the size is differs but when I get coordinates for x1 and x2. PHP crops the image as if it is the browser image(small image) and that gives me the wrong part of the image.

So that the question is that how do I get X1 and X2 of an image regardless of the size but starting from the same exact pixel.?

Comment: It's quite challenging to understand the question too, is it related to css at all?

Comment: nooo, imagine a small div box. but on there is a mark on that box. now how do i mark the same exact spot on a bigger box but in the same relative coordinates

Comment: ?? here is some funny test made a couple of years ago http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/ogoqWa is that what your question is about ?

Comment: yes, you're a guineas.

Comment: Now how to i get such coordinates of  an image